# VueJS and Keep-Alive: Why the console error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a view/page called `posts` that I want to show with a list of posts. Let's assume that this page would contain thousands of posts. Thus, I only want to load it once, and if the user navigates to a different page of the app and then returns back to the `posts` page, I don't want to make an API call and load all the posts again.

I saw that Vue has something called `<keep-alive>` which can cache certain routes/components: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Here's what I tried:

```
<keep-alive :include="posts">
    <RouterView :key="$route.name" class="pb-5"/>
</keep-alive>
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out why it won't work for my demo. I get a console error like so:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

```
found in

---> <App> at /src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

Anyone have any tips on what I am doing wrong? Here's my codesandbox demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v010-65o4r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `:` binding from `include`, otherwise it's looking for a data property called `posts` in your `App` component instead of the literal string "posts".

```html
<keep-alive include="posts">
    <RouterView :key="$route.name" class="pb-5"/>
</keep-alive>
```

You also need to give your `Posts` component the name "posts", because the `keep-alive` `include` refers to a component name and your component doesn't have one:

```js
export default {
  name: "posts",  // <-- Add this
  components: {
    PostsList
  }
};
```